# Using a Json file inside a Razor page

Tags: c#, json, .net, razor

I have a website made with C#/.NET Razor page, where I need to enter ZipCode, Region and country at differents places.

I have a JSON file inside my project where I have the regions related to the zip code.

I would like to use this JSON file to suggest and complet the region according to the zip code.
[image]

How can I achieve that ?

- make an API and call it while I need it ?
  or
- there is a way to create list in the backend and load it on some page ?

Thank you for the answer

Comment: You could add the data to a database and the create a stored procedure that will suggest using a partial match against the ZIP Code column using `WHERE ZipCode LIKE '%@Text%'` Or query the table using linq and use `where z.zipCodes.Contains(text)`.

Comment: Indeed, better performance with database I guess. Now I need to find a way to add all json data to the database.

Comment: You could always use a online tool as the data is not sensitive.